# Take a class as a parameter which has a particular method in it

Tags: java, class, kotlin, methods

I know that we can pass a class in a param which has a particular class as its super. For example, see this:

```java
public void sampleMethod(Class<? super MyParentClass> class){
   // my random code 
}
```

and in kotlin:

```kotlin
fun sampleMethod(class:Class<? super MyParentClass>){
   // my random code 
}
```

But, can I have something like this?:

```java
public void sampleMethod(Class <? hasMethod myMethod> class){
   // my random code 
}
```

or in Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun sampleMethod(class:Class<? hasMethod MyParentClass>){
   // my random code 
}
```

Basically I only want to accept a class in that param which has a method mentioned in it. Is it possible?

If yes, I want the code in java and Kotlin

If no, then any alternative will be ok

### Edit

---

Most of the answers here are not what I want. So, I am explaining it a bit more here:

```
public class MyClass1{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      doRandomTask(new ClassWhichHasMethod()); // works fine
      doRandomTask(new ClassWhichDoesNotHaveMethod()); // gives error as it does not have that method
   }

   static class ClassWhichHasMethod{
      public void theMethodIWant(){} // the method I want to check
   }

   static class ClassWhichDoesNotHaveMethod{ // no method here}

   public static void doRandomTask(Class<? hasMethod theMethodIWant> class){
      // my random code 
   }

}
```

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear about what I want

Comment: What you want is **not** possible without using interfaces.

Comment: Ok @Olivier. Just wanted to know if it possible or not. I won't bother that thou. That was never what I wanted in my project. Just curiosity.

Comment: Could you share the code of `doRandomTask`, so it's easier to understand the problem? The example is somewhat confusing - `doRandomTask(new ClassWhichHasMethod());` will not compile, because `doRandomTask` is declared to accept parameter of type `Class<?>` and neither `ClassWhichHasMethod`, nor `ClassWhichDoesNotHaveMethod` are such.

Comment: Do you want to pass an instance describing the class or do you want to pass an instance of a class, i.e. an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an *interface* to do that. When an object implements an interface, that guarantees that it has the methods, properties etc that the interface defines. You don't need to know what *class* the object is, just that it can be treated as the interface's type:

```
interface MethodHaver {
    fun myCoolMethod(something: String)
}

class Whatever : MethodHaver {
    // need to implement/override the method in the interface to satisfy the contract
    override fun myCoolMethod(something: String) {
        // do a thing
    }
}

class SomethingElse {
    // uses anything that implements MethodHaver
    fun doTheThing(myObject: MethodHaver) {
        // the object definitely has this method, because the MethodHaver type requires it
        myObject.myCoolMethod("wow")
    }
}
```

---

You can do it with anonymous objects too, doesn't have to be classes

```
SomethingElse().doTheThing(object : MethodHaver {
    override fun myCoolMethod(something: String) {
        // do something
    }
})
```

Or, in Kotlin, since the interface only has one method, you can make it a [functional interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html), and then you can pass a lambda instead that matches the single method's signature:

```
// note the 'fun' keyword before 'interface'
fun interface MethodHaver {
    fun myCoolMethod(something: String)
}

// pass a lambda that matches the method signature, i.e. takes a String and returns Unit (doesn't return anything)
SomethingElse().doTheThing { something -> // do something }
```

---

And finally, in Kotlin you can skip the interfaces and use function types instead

```
class SomethingElse {
    // accepts any function that takes a String and returns Unit
    fun doTheThing(f: (String) -> Unit) {
        // call the passed function like any other
        f("wow")
    }
}

// has the method you're interested in, but it isn't implementing an interface
class ClassWithMethod {
    fun someMethod(string: String) {
        println(string)
    }
}

fun main() {
    // call it passing a lambda
    SomethingElse().doTheThing { println(it) }

    // or pass a function reference, like a method on a specific object
    val myClass = ClassWithMethod()
    SomethingElse().doTheThing(myClass::someMethod)
}
```

With the function reference example there, instead of having to pass *an object that has a particular method*, you can just pass *a reference to the method itself*. So instead of having to involve interfaces (so the type system can confirm you're passing a valid object with the appropriate method), you can cut out the middleman and pass the method itself directly. So long as its signature matches (parameters and return type), it's valid

So yeah, lots of options depending on exactly what you need to do!